# Recognizing first user login (Node.js/JWT)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I've developed an authentication system who consists on Node.js/Express and JWT.

I need to recognize the first time a user logs on and show him a message relevant only on that one time.
How can I do it?

This is the auth middleware i'm using to verify the user:

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("x-auth-token")

    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg : "No token, authorization failed" })

    
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"))
        
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    }
    catch {
        res.status(400).json({ msg : "Token is not valid" })
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on how your client is implemented.

Comment: Client side is implemented with React

Comment: Then the provided answer is correct and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For this approach, you should let User to login with Basic Authentication for the first time (Email/Username + Password). After you validate that the user is the valid user on the backend, then you should store his `_id` in JWT and send him that JWT. On each next request, that user should send that JWT, and you can use your JWT authentication (but for initial login, you should go with Basic Authentication).